# Setar CLASSPATH para ser acessível no Apache

Tags: java, apache, django, python-2.7, variáveis-de-ambiente

Como faço para a variável de ambiente `CLASSPATH` ser acessível pelo apache?

Tenho um projeto Django que utiliza a biblioteca `python-weka-wrapper` que faz uma ponte entre a implementação em Java do Weka.

Tudo funciona perfeitamente no servidor de desenvolvimento Django, no entanto, quando rodo no apache recebo um erro refente a não ter encontrado a `LibSVM` uma biblioteca necessária para execução do código.

Fiz um `export` da seguinte maneira.

```
export CLASSPATH=/home/wilker/wekafiles/packages/LibSVM/LibSVM.jar:/home/wilker/wekafiles/packages/LibSVM/lib/libsvm.jar
```

Porém acredito que não esteja acessível dentro do apache.

Answer (score 0):

O algoritmo `libSVM` não vem nativamente no WEKA até a versão 3.8.2, você deve adicionar o pacote pela tela inicial do WEKA, na guia `TOOLS -> Package manager`